# Error Can't resolve all parameters for LoginComponent: when implement Nebular Oauth2

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular, ngx-admin

I'm trying to use nebular oauth exactly like in the docs, but in logincomponent but the different is i extend nebular login component. But this code gives me an error

```
export class LoginComponent extends NbLoginComponent implements OnDestroy {
  public user: SocialUser;
  private loggedIn: boolean;
  constructor(service: NbAuthService,options: {},cd: ChangeDetectorRef, router: Router) {
    super(service,{},cd, router);
  }

  alive = true;

  login() {
    this.service.authenticate('google')
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
      .subscribe((authResult: NbAuthResult) => {
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.alive = false;
  }
}
```

[image]

what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i just fixed it, the problem is i'm not using the `NB_AUTH_OPTIONS` injection token to resolve `options`  so the code should be like this

```
constructor(service: NbAuthService,@Inject(NB_AUTH_OPTIONS) options: {},cd: ChangeDetectorRef, router: Router) {
    super(service,options,cd, router);
  }

  alive = true;
  login() {
    this.service.authenticate('google')
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
      .subscribe((authResult: NbAuthResult) => {
      });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.alive = false;
  }
```